# Quasar x Capasitor mobile app build Geo location not working in xcode

Tags: ios, quasar-framework, quasar

im having some troubles with building my ios and android application from my quasar and capasitor application.

my dependancies are not coming through (im using geo location, and its working fine in dev on browser) but as soon as i build and when i spin it up in the xcode simulator it throws an unimplamented error code for the geolocation (getting the user location)

im not sure what is happening, and i cant find any documentation on this online

expecting to get the location of the current user

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.